# How to remove a write-back EnhanceIO cache on root partition?

Tags: btrfs, initramfs, 15.04, enhanceio

I accidentially created a write-back EnhanceIO cache for my root partition. I didn't know that

> Creating a writeback cache on root device is not supported. This is because the root device is mounted as read only prior to the processing of udev rules.

as stated on the [Persistence.txt of EnhanceIO](https://github.com/stec-inc/EnhanceIO/blob/master/Documents/Persistence.txt).

I create a LRU write-back cache for the device which contains my btrfs root filesystem with `eio_cli`, used it and rebooted. The filesystem is no longer mountable due to the isses described in the citation above. I manipulated the `initramfs` image in a live system and inserted the kernel modules  `enhanceio.ko`, `enhanceio_lru.ko` and `enhanceio_fifo.ko`. I don't seem to find a way to attempt a resuce.

I'm uncertain whether the device can be restored externally by creating the same cache in another system and cleaning the cache there.

I'm using Linux 3.19.3 on Ubuntu 15.04-beta2.